# How to use assemble to add a directory of markdown files to my index

Tags: gruntjs, yaml, markdown, assemble

I'm trying to add static site generation to a site in order to make it more organised and easier to contribute to. The index file has a section with with an unordered list and a number of list items that all share the same formatting. I would like to dynamically load these list items from a folder of markdown files.

I'm trying to do something like

```
{{forEach file in the folder}}
<li>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="display">
      {{markdown content of the file}}
    </div>
    <div class="code">
      <pre>
        <code class="language-javascript">
          {{ string from YFM in markdown file }}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
{{/forEach}}
```

I don't actually want each markdown file to be assembled into it's own page in my dist folder, just used as a dynamic collection of partials for my index file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two parts of an apparently never finished tutorial explain how to use markdown files as a dynamic collection of partials to integrate on the index site:

- http://www.andismith.com/blog/2014/02/getting-started-with-assemble/
- http://www.andismith.com/blog/2014/02/creating-a-list-of-posts-in-assemble/

Inside the loop that's iterating the md files I used this construct to get the yfm-stripped content "included" as content on the index site (took me quite a while to figure out):

```
{{#markdown}}
  {{page}}
{{/markdown}}
```

Also refer to the documentation on Collections on http://assemble.io, but careful, there's some conflicting information out there as to the options hash for collections (`name: posts` vs. `name: post`, that is, singular vs. plural and autoinflection vs. `inflection: post`, but bottom line: stick with the variant in the links above :))